# How to build up commenting privileges?

Tags: discussion

I want to comment on a question and provide some feedback but I can’t.

How can I build up privilege quickly so I can comment?

Comment: Am I able to comment now?

Comment: You can *always* comment on your own questions and answers. And well, its 50 rep - I've earned that on a single good answer.

Comment: Ask a good question or post a good high quality answer

Comment: Related (but tongue-in-cheek): [Six simple tips to get reputation fast on any Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/195817).

Answer (score 7):

You acquire *privileges* by building up your *reputation*.
These concepts are discussed in the Help Center:
[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)
and [List of privileges you can earn](https://superuser.com/help/privileges).
The short version is: there are basically three ways to get reputation:

- Find questions that you can answer, and answer them.
- Ask *new, intelligent, well-researched* questions.
  This is sometimes harder than writing answers.
- Find posts (questions and answers) with severe problems (typically in formatting or English)
  and edit them.

Answer (score 0):

I still find really strange that (apparently) newbies are allowed to edit others users posts but not allowed to add comments (to ask for more detailed explanation on a solution for instance)

Comment: Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Sorry for the jargon usage (this forums seem to have really strict posting rules). And regarding my initial question, since I'm a "new user" (regarding superuser, not in general) I'm getting very frustrated when I find a answer which is false or incomplete and I'm unable to comment because I'm lacking reputation.

Comment: And sorry too for the delayed answer: I've setup email notifications but unfortunately this is not working for me (I hope that feature is not of reputation level dependent too)