# How do you use Super User and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I have come across several questions/answers that I would like to vote up or contribute to. However, I am not cool enough with reputation points.

Anyone know how you can be cool without asking meaningless questions?

Comment: Give good answers.

Comment: Good answers include links, sometimes images...

I spent 30 min researching a "good answer" to find a screenshot would have helped immensely.

Only problem, I couldn't upload images for the next guy.

Comment: @Josh221 those restrictions are in place for users under 10 rep points to help prevent spam. The good thing is, it only takes one upvote on one of your answers to hit 10 points and remove that limitation.

Comment: Then, until you get reputation, post answers without links or use dead text links and ask nicely for someone with reputation to edit them in for you. If you spent 30 minutes writing an answer then its a small time difference to make it postable with basic text only. Good answers don't *need* links, but I will admit that great answers can provide extra detail in citations and images.

Comment: If you spent 30 minutes writing an answer.  The amount of reputation you would receive from that answer. Would allow you to do more then just add inline images into an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build up comment privileges?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8634/150988)   … also [How to get reputation on Unix & Linux stack exchange?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3484/23408)

Comment: @Scott it can't be a dupe of something on another different site.

Comment: @nhinkle: The first one is on this site.  Would it have been OK if I had said "See also ..."?

Comment: Downvoted, this makes absolutely no sense...

Answer (score 25):

Thanks for your interest in participating! The reputation system can be a little bit confusing at first, but rest assured - it's not that we think you aren't cool.

Start out by [taking the tour](https://superuser.com/tour). It explains all the basic concepts of how the site works. If you check out the [privileges page](https://superuser.com/help/privileges) you can see how much reputation each new privilege requires and how close you are.

There are several ways to gain reputation without just posting questions. The foremost is to post answers. There is almost certainly a question here somewhere you know the answer to. You can browse the [unanswered questions list](https://superuser.com/unanswered) to find some. Every upvote on an answer you write is worth +10. You can also suggest helpful edits to existing questions or answers. Every approved edit is worth +2.

It won't take you long to get the 15 points required to upvote, and with a little bit of effort you'll soon have the 50 points required to comment.